# Is Induction Wattmeter ,Energy Meter and Watt Hour Meter the same thing

Tags: measurement, instrumentation

I have a topic to study regarding Energy Meters. In the Syllabus it says Energy Meter, in the textbook it says Induction Wattmeter and one [online reference  by IIT](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/108105053/pdf/L-44%28GDR%29%28ET%29%20%28%28EE%29NPTEL%29.pdf), says WattHour Meter/Induction Type Energy Meter.

Are all these things the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wattmeter tells you the power being pumped into a target load. If the load consumes 100 watts the meter reads 100 watts. If power drops to zero watts the meter reads zero watts. Should the power be flowing in the opposite direction the wattmeter will read a negative value: -

[image]

Note that the meter will read zero in the centre of the scale should it be an analogue meter as depicted in the picture above. [Here's](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_8/11.html) where the picture came from.

An energy meter will totalize power over a given time period producing a reading in joules (watt seconds) or watt hours. It must also be able to differentiate negative values of power from positive amounts of power. It's basically formed by adding an integrator to the output of a wattmeter.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.so a Watt Hour meter/Energy Meter give the average power consumed over a period of time while the watt meter gives the instantaneous power.So an Induction Type Wattmeter != A Watthour Meter

Answer (score 2):

A first-step classification for you to initially navigate yourself and start lurking (learning) from:

By market:

- smart energy meter => microprocessor-based meter, typically static energy meter, suppoted with communication ability (wi-fi, modem, ethrnet, rs485, etc...)
- convetional energy meter => non-microprocessor based meter, having no communication ability
- revenue energy meter => smart poly-phase energy meter, with additional functions such as tariffs, profiles, quality measurement, etc...

By measuring principle:

- static energy meter => microprocessor-based meter, employs ADC and DSP techniques
- inductive energy meter => conventional, non-microprocessor based meter, employs analog calculations

By mesuring quantity:

- watt-hour energy meter => active energy meter, measures dissipated power (W*h)
- volt-ampere-reactive energy meter => reactive energy meter, measures non-dissipated power (var)
- volt-ampere energy meter => apparent energy meter, measures both dissipated and non-dissipated power (V*A)

Comment: Thanks..but im a novice and these terms confuse me.